# Crash Error with SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I tried to take a Properties of Workflow, SharePoint Designer is getting crash. I tried many times with different SharePoint lists and SharePoint Servers.

When i take Context Menu on SharePoint, or take  a properties of Workflow:

[image]

I get a Designer Crash. I tried this many times:

[image]

How Could I Fix this ?

Comment: try to repair sharepoint designer in control panel

Comment: I tried and Reinstal too and not helps.

Comment: than it happens because of another program that sharepoint designer uses to show properties of workflow 
I will check which programs are needed to show workflow properties and I will let you know if I find something useful

Comment: If You Can please find Out wchich programs wil be Use to show propeties of workflow.